# How to bulk edit a meta_value with mysql query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

On my wordpress I have a little over 1000 posts which I'm looking to update a certain meta_vale of a particular meta_key and was wondering how I can do this with mysql. The meta_key I need to update is "Crafting" and I want to update every meta_value that currently has 40 / 400 (Golden) to just 400. "Crafting" has other values so I only want to update the ones that have the 40 / 400 (Golden) meta_value to 400.

What I've found so far but need some help finishing the query.

```
REPLACE INTO `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id`
, `post_id`
, `meta_key`
, `meta_value`
)
SELECT
      `meta_id`
    , `post_id`
    , "Crafting"
    , "40 / 400 (Golden)" -- assuming all posts to be set the same
```

After this I'm not really sure how what to.

Comment: Remember to vote up or accept the answer that is most helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question, you want to update the `meta_value` field to `400` in all posts that have `meta_key = 'crafting'` and `meta_value = '40 / 400 (Golden)'`?

If so, a simple `Update` statement will work:

```
update wp_postmeta
set meta_value = '400'
where meta_value = '40 / 400 (Golden)'
    and meta_key = 'Crafting'
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I"m looking to do.